# Ag-grid Blank Cells setting for text filter

Tags: javascript, angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-rid to display a table where the last 100 rows are BLANKS(NULL values for each column). I need this to simulate EXCEL's behavior so that the user can edit this cells.

Today I introduce filtering and I want to ignore the empty rows, so that the user can fill the empty cells even if a filter is applied.

I found the "[Blank Cells](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#blank-cells-date-and-number-filters)" section on the filtering documentation and this seems exactly what I need. But for some reason it works only for date and number filters.
Any idea how I can achieve this for the text filter?

Comment: This seems to be fixed with AG Grid Enterprise 27.0.1

Comment: @BeninCA, do you have a link?

Comment: I don't have a link to any documentation, but I was on 26.2, and blanks didn't work in the Enterprise filter selection, and upgraded to 27.0.1, and then it was working.